# Keras model.fit() TypeError: Cannot convert a symbolic Keras input/output to a numpy array

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, curve-fitting

I get an error when fitting the model with Keras `model.fit()` :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\username\Documents\FAE\Maths\Code\variational auto encoders\continuous text generation\variational_autoencoder_text_gen_V2\vae_train.py", line 87, in <module>
    vae.fit([x, x_decoder], x, epochs=epochs, verbose=1)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1184, in fit
    tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 885, in __call__
    result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 933, in _call
    self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializers)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 759, in _initialize
    self._stateful_fn._get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(  # pylint: disable=protected-access
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 3066, in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected
    graph_function, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 3463, in _maybe_define_function
    graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 3298, in _create_graph_function
    func_graph_module.func_graph_from_py_func(
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py", line 1007, in func_graph_from_py_func
    func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 668, in wrapped_fn
    out = weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py", line 994, in wrapper
    raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
TypeError: in user code:

    C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py:853 train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py:842 step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:1286 run
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:2849 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:3632 _call_for_each_replica
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py:835 run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py:788 train_step
        loss = self.compiled_loss(
    C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\compile_utils.py:239 __call__
        self._loss_metric.update_state(
    C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\metrics_utils.py:73 decorated
        update_op = update_state_fn(*args, **kwargs)
    C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\metrics.py:177 update_state_fn
        return ag_update_state(*args, **kwargs)
    C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\metrics.py:409 update_state  **
        sample_weight = tf.__internal__.ops.broadcast_weights(
    C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\weights_broadcast_ops.py:157 broadcast_weights
        values = ops.convert_to_tensor(values, name="values")
    C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\profiler\trace.py:163 wrapped
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py:1566 convert_to_tensor
        ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
    C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py:346 _constant_tensor_conversion_function
        return constant(v, dtype=dtype, name=name)
    C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py:271 constant
        return _constant_impl(value, dtype, shape, name, verify_shape=False,
    C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py:288 _constant_impl
        tensor_util.make_tensor_proto(
    C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\tensor_util.py:435 make_tensor_proto
        values = np.asarray(values)
    C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_asarray.py:83 asarray
        return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
    C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\keras_tensor.py:244 __array__
        raise TypeError(

    TypeError: Cannot convert a symbolic Keras input/output to a numpy array. This error may indicate that you're trying to pass a symbolic value to a NumPy call, which is not supported. Or, you may be trying to pass Keras symbolic inputs/outputs to a TF API that does not register dispatching, preventing Keras from automatically converting the API call to a lambda layer in the Functional Model.
```

Here the code for data preparation

```
from gensim.utils import tokenize

from lstm_vae import create_lstm_vae, inference


def get_text_data(data_path, num_samples=1000):

    # vectorize the data
    input_texts = []
    input_characters = set(["\t"])

    with open(data_path, "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        lines = f.read().lower().split("\n")

    for line in lines[: min(num_samples, len(lines) - 1)]:
        input_text = line.split("\t")[0]
        # input_text = word_tokenize(input_text) # using nltk
        input_text = list ( tokenize (input_text) ) # using gensim
        input_text.append("<end>")

        input_texts.append(input_text)

        for char in input_text:
            if char not in input_characters:
                input_characters.add(char)

    input_characters = sorted(list(input_characters))
    num_encoder_tokens = len(input_characters)
    max_encoder_seq_length = max([len(txt) for txt in input_texts]) + 1

    print("Number of samples:", len(input_texts))
    print("Number of unique input tokens:", num_encoder_tokens)
    print("Max sequence length for inputs:", max_encoder_seq_length)

    input_token_index = dict([(char, i) for i, char in enumerate(input_characters)])
    reverse_input_char_index = dict((i, char) for char, i in input_token_index.items())

    encoder_input_data = np.zeros((len(input_texts), max_encoder_seq_length, num_encoder_tokens), dtype="float32")
    decoder_input_data = np.zeros((len(input_texts), max_encoder_seq_length, num_encoder_tokens), dtype="float32")

    for i, input_text in enumerate(input_texts):
        decoder_input_data[i, 0, input_token_index["\t"]] = 1.0

        for t, char in enumerate(input_text):
            encoder_input_data[i, t, input_token_index[char]] = 1.0
            decoder_input_data[i, t + 1, input_token_index[char]] = 1.0

    return max_encoder_seq_length, num_encoder_tokens, input_characters, input_token_index, reverse_input_char_index, \
           encoder_input_data, decoder_input_data
```

and the `main` code

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

    timesteps_max, enc_tokens, characters, char2id, id2char, x, x_decoder = get_text_data(num_samples=3000,
                                                                                          data_path="data/fra.txt")

    print ( x[0] )

    print(x.shape, "Creating model...")

    input_dim = x.shape[-1]
    timesteps = x.shape[-2]
    batch_size = 1
    latent_dim = 191
    intermediate_dim = 353
    epochs = 40

    vae, enc, gen, stepper = create_lstm_vae(input_dim,
                                             batch_size=batch_size,
                                             intermediate_dim=intermediate_dim,
                                             latent_dim=latent_dim)
    print("Training model...")

    vae.fit([x, x_decoder], x, epochs=epochs, verbose=1)
```

So, the last line is producing the error.

Data inspection, when i do

```
    print("Number of samples:", len(input_texts))
    print("Number of unique input tokens:", num_encoder_tokens)
    print("Max sequence length for inputs:", max_encoder_seq_length)

    print ( x[0] )
```

gives

```
Number of samples: 3000
Number of unique input tokens: 742
Max sequence length for inputs: 6
[[0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]]
```

Disabling eager execution as suggested in [Tensorflow Model fit format data correctly -- TypeError: Cannot convert a symbolic Keras input/output to a numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69033906/tensorflow-model-fit-format-data-correctly-typeerror-cannot-convert-a-symbol) enable to execute the fit function, however i fear it is not the proper way. Maybe related to the way the custom loss is defined ?

```
def vae_loss(x, x_decoded_onehot):
    # xent_loss = objectives.categorical_crossentropy(x, x_decoded_onehot) # seems deprecated
    xent_loss = losses.CategoricalCrossentropy()(x, x_decoded_onehot)
    kl_loss = - 0.5 * K.mean(1 + z_log_sigma - K.square(z_mean) - K.exp(z_log_sigma))
    loss = xent_loss + kl_loss
    return loss
```

What would you suggest ?

Comment: Could it be that you're using a numpy function in your model class?

Comment: In the `vae_loss` could you replace `keras.backend.mean()/.square()/.exp()` by `tf.math.square()/.mean()/.exp()` and check the error code? Also for `loss = xent_loss + kl_loss` could you try `tf.math.add(xent_loss, kl_loss)`

Comment: Last hint: could you try and decorate your `vae_loss` function by the `@tf.function`. This would ensure your loss func is wrapped into a graph func

Comment: no numpy function

Comment: @AlexandreMahdhaoui code is fully operational when disabling eager mode, model trains and predicts as expected, should i bother turning eager mode on ... ?

Comment: @kiriloff eager_execution is usefull for development and debugging purposes. If your code is ready for production, you could indeed disable eager

Comment: @kiriloff Please add `model.compile` line. Also please try to use a built-in loss function instead of your own, such as `mse` and see do you still get error or not. Your custom loss function looks fine. However I want to make sure.